# Is it possible to map audit table "AbpAuditLogs" to a class?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm going to use this table to keep tracking the history of a certain entity and show to the user. I need to map the AbpAuditLog to an entity or already exist a way to do this?

I want to make queries on this table using Entity Framework. Is it possible?

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History

Comment: Ok, but I need to make queries on this table using EntityFramework. How can I do it?

Comment: That's for EF Core.

Comment: But I need to create an Entity that inherits from AuditInfo so I cant query this table with EF Core or I'm gonna have to query this table with raw SQL?

Comment: you can implement your own AuditLogProvider https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d8702f389aa1f5947d3446f16aec845287/src/Abp/Auditing/DefaultAuditInfoProvider.cs